# Trying to display backend sent SVG in Angular

Tags: html, angular, xml, svg

I am trying to display SVG image which I receive from API, it is a huge array full of various data and one of them is SVG property.

It pretty much looks like this in raw form:

```
"svg": "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\n<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 23.0.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->\n<svg version=\"1.1\" id=\"Layer_1\" xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\" xmlns:xlink=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink\" x=\"0px\" y=\"0px\"\n\t viewBox=\"0 0 500 500\" style=\"enable-background:new 0 0 500 500;\" xml:space=\"preserve\">\n<style type=\"text/css\">\n\t.st0{fill:#8C3A2D;}\n</style>\n<rect class=\"st0\" width=\"500\" height=\"500\"/>\n</svg>"
```

I tried using the following HTML format for this data:

```
<div (click)="clickItem(item)" *ngIf="item" class="smallSquare" [innerHTML]="item.svg | safeHtml"></div>
```

As you can see I even added safeHtml pipe to pass security restriction, yet all I get is a blank square and nothing more. I can't seem to figure out what I am missing here.

If I inspect the element in the console I see following form of file:

```
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 500 500" style="enable-background:new 0 0 500 500;" xml:space="preserve">
<style type="text/css">
    .st0{fill:#462928;}
</style>
<rect class="st0" width="500" height="500"></rect>
</svg>
```

It seems that all is fine, but sadly I don't see any preview, instead, I have a blank square without any color in it.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bLXwc.png)

Comment: Seems like .st0{fill:#5B4085;}, this part is not working for some reason

Answer (score 2):

The problem was caused by the stacking of styles with SVG icons. Multiple SVGs came back with the same style class="st0", because of this, colors were stacking up on each other.